# SIFT or SURF - Provide key points and retrieve descriptors

Tags: python, opencv, surf, sift

I am trying to use OpenCV(2.4.6.0) to retrieve descriptors from key points that I have provided.

So far, I have not been successful...

```
l, des = surf.detectAndCompute(self.gray,None,useProvidedKeypoints = True)
```

where `l` is an array of feature points. I am not sure where to input the key points I already have...

Would anyone know how I can go about doing this with either SIFT or SURF?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a problem with the Python bindings for `detectAndCompute()`, since the C++ equivalent does allow inputting of keypoints. Fortunately, there is a workaround. If you already have detected keypoints and stored them in `l`, then you can create a `DescriptorExtractor` object and compute descriptors for the provided keypoints.

An example generating FAST keypoints and then computing SURF descriptors follows:

```
im = cv2.imread(path_to_image)
fast = cv2.FeatureDetector_create('FAST')
l = fast.detect(im)
surf = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create('SURF')
l, des = surf.compute(im, l)
```

This works equally well for SIFT features. Just pass `'SIFT'` as an argument to `cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create()` instead.

Comment: Hi Aurelius, when I try this solution I find that the value of `l` changes. I printed `l` before and after the line `l, des = surf.compute(im, l)` and noticed new key points were being generated in `l`. Thanks for your help.